# Negative Index from a List<UIControl>?

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, list, indexing

I have a List, a click event to Add a button, and a click event for each button created to show a Message.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Button> btnList = new List<Button>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void createbtn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Button btn = new Button();

       // wp is a WrapPanel in the MainWindow
       wp.Children.Add(btn);

       btn.Content = "Hello";
       btn.Click += hello_btn_Click;
       btnList.Add(btn);
    }

    private void hello_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Button b = sender as Button;
       var bIndex = btnList.IndexOf(b);
       MessageBox.Show(bIndex.ToString());  
    }
}
```

Now the code is edited and runs OK.

Comment: You ask about a `List<UIElement>` but your code shows a `List<Button>`; now, it wouldn't *matter*, but can you clarify? as there are a few discrepencies in the question; the other I mention in my answer. Debugging from a snippet is hard enough, but it gets harder if the snippet itself confuses the issue by misrepresentation

Comment: @Marc, I have amended my question. Hope that clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have 2 lists (`btnLink` and `btnList`), and are getting them confused:

```
btnLink.Add(btn);
...
var bIndex = btnList.IndexOf(b);
```

Comment: @KMC was it a typo in *your code*? or in the question here? If in your code, that is all that is needed to show this symptom. If you add an object to list A, and look for it in list B, you will get -1 since it *isn't in* list B.